# Why does this function return void?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, es6-promise

Here is my `useSend` function, I am working with Typescript + React.

```js
const useSend = (method: string, url: string, data: any): Promise<string> => {
    return fetch(url, {
        method: method,
        headers: { 
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json", },
        credentials: 'include',
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
    })
    .then((response) => {  
        if (response.status === 200) {
            return "success";
        } else {
            response.json()
            .then((resp) => {
                return resp;
            })
        }
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
        return err;
    });
}
 
export default useSend;
```

When I call `.then` on `useSend`, an error is always thrown:

> ```
> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')
> ```

```js
function useSubmit (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const form = new FormData(event.currentTarget);
    const data = { email: form.get('email'), password: form.get('password') };
    
    useSend("POST", "http://localhost:2999/login", data)
        .then((temp: string) => {
            console.log(temp);
            result = temp;
            if (result == "success") {
                window.location.href = "/feed/latest";
        }
    })
}
```

I have made changes to the return statements and block structures but nothing helps. Can someone help to explain why void is returned by this function even tho I have used then at every step to get the outer function to return after the promise is resolved?

Comment: @Pac0 I have just updated it, thank you for helping!

Comment: We don't know where the `then` property is being read from `undefined`.  Can you please provide the full stack trace?

Comment: Given the code you have provided, I cannot reproduce the error you describe. Here's a running demo [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/why-does-this-function-return-void-48s2t9). Feel free to fork it and add more of your actual code to see if you can create a reproducible example we can inspect live. In the meantime, please [edit] to include the complete error message and any accompanying error stacktrace.

Comment: whenever I see code like `.then((resp) => { return resp; })` it indicates a fundamental lack of knowledge of Promises ... i.e. that code is completely unrequired

Comment: are you sure the error is due to `.then((temp: string) => {` and not a different `.then` somewhere else?

Comment: Hi all, adding `return` in front of `response.json()` as @GregFenton suggests does resolve the problem of it returning undefined. However, I am too unsure why the error message does not persist, it has happened to me a couple of times. I am very sorry for the confusion. Thanks a lot!

Comment: For starters, this `response.json().then()` needs to be `return response.json().then()`.  You aren't returning the JSON value so it just gets lost and the promise takes on a `undefined` resolved value because the return value from the parent `.then()` handler is `undefined` as you have no return statement in it.

Comment: Er....so the error message of `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')` goes away if your put `return` in front of `response.json()` ?

Comment: Also, there's no `void` here.  The resolved value of your promise is `undefined`, not `void`.  It's important to learn the right terminology, especially when asking questions of others.

Comment: "I am too unsure why the error message does not persist" - Perhaps you have an issue still elsewhere in your code. If you could post the complete error message and stacktrace readers here can be better equipped to help you. As-is right now, the error you describe is not reproducible.

Answer (score 1):

First, you are naming something `useSend()` that is not a React Hook.  You'd be better off renaming this function to something that does not start with `useXXXXX()`.

Second, you do not have `return` in front of `response.json().then(.......)` so for that clause you are not returning a value.

Third, it would be useful if you provided the full stack trace and not just the error message.  The full stack trace should indicate the code the error is coming from.

[Edit] Fourth, as @Pac0 suggests in his comment, please provide the code that actually calls `useSend()` as that's the code where the error is being thrown from.

Comment: none of that should cause the useSend function to not return a Promise, would it?

Comment: Likely true...but I would very much like to see a `return` in front of `response.json()`.  As I have mentioned elsewhere, we aren't sure where the `then` is being read from `undefined`.  Maybe it is in `useSend()` itself??

Comment: This should have been a comment, since you are not actually answering the question. And you can't say you don't have enough points to post a comment...

Comment: I haven't had validation that my SECOND point resolves (or not) the situation.  Happy to remove if the OP validates a non-match.

Comment: Greg, I can verify/validate that point 2 is not the issue. See my linked [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/why-does-this-function-return-void-48s2t9). Probably best to delete the answer for now while the OP gets their stuff together.

Comment: a-a-a-a-and, we're back.  I hope.

Comment: @DrewReese - if you change your sandbox's return value from `fetch()` to return `undefined` instead of an object (which I expect happens when a network error occurs?), then you get the exact same error message as the OP.  Here's [my fork of your sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/why-does-this-function-return-void-forked-y647ww?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A82%2C1).  Open the browser dev tools >> Console to see the error.

Comment: Returning undefined produces a different error though, e.g. not being able to read "status" of undefined. The real `fetch` function doesn't return `undefined` though, it will [*always* resolve with some Response or throw an error/Rejection if there is a network error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#checking_that_the_fetch_was_successful). And OP's issue is about chaining from a returned Promise, or rather ***not*** being able to.